# Unauthenticated requests are not allowed. Take out a new plan or start a free trial at https://pro.bitcoinaverage.com

Tags: api, flutter, http, dart, authentication

I want to print BTC conversion to other currencies. I am using bitcoinaverage. On the browser, the URL is not working. The screen displays this "Unauthenticated requests are not allowed. Take out a new plan or start a free trial at https://pro.bitcoinaverage.com". I am using Flutter. On console, it is giving a 404 error. The following is the code snippet.

```
const bitcoinAverageURL = 'https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/average/ticker';    
Future getCoinData(String selectedCurrency) async {
        var authKey = '$bitcoinAverageURL/BTCAUD';
        http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(authKey));
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          var decodedData = jsonDecode(response.body);
          double current = decodedData['last'];
          return current.toStringAsFixed(0);
        } else {
          print(response.statusCode);
          throw 'Problem with get request';
        }
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue today, is there any working fix for the same, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation:

```
All requests to our API must be authenticated with your public key.
```

You need to autrhorize on API site and get your API access token. API usage described in [Official documentation](https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/).

Try to add your API key to header:

```dart
await http.get(
  Uri.parse(url),
  headers: {
    'x-ba-key': 'your_api_key',
  },
);
```

Comment: I have used the API key in the URL. But I am having the same issue.

Comment: Thanks that worked... :) @Usama, you might have to generate a new api key. Give it a try and let us know :)